# Boolean Algebra Transform

Tags: logic, boolean-algebra, propositional-calculus

I am revisiting Boolean algebra after a long while.

Can somebody help show me how to simplify the LHS to get the RHS?

> $$abc * a'bc + (abc)' * (a'bc)'\quad = \quad \;b'+c'$$

Comment: What is * and + ? AND and OR?

Comment: Yes, they are AND and OR.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

$$\color{blue}{\bf abc * a'bc} + (abc)' * (a'bc)'$$

Note: $$\color{blue}{\bf abc*a'bc} = abca'bc = (aa')bbcc = F*bc = \color{blue}{\bf F}$$

So we simplify what remains:  $$\color{blue}{\bf F} + (abc)' * (a'bc)' = (abc)' * (a'bc)'$$ $$ = (a'+b'+c')*(a + b' + c')\tag{ by Demorgan's.}$$

$$ = (b' + c')+ (a' * a)\tag{Distributive law}$$ 
$$ = b' + c' + F  $$
$$= b' + c'$$

Comment: I only shave once a week, but the beard and moustache never really grow in like I'd like! :-)

Comment: Hello, @Babak! Did you sleep well?

Comment: @amWhy: Oh yes Amy. If we could make levels for sleeping exactly the same as we get + up to 250 up voting every day; I got 210 for that last night. :D

Comment: @amWhy: So; go sleep. You brain needs it. Angels are all waiting to greet you in Heaven with all you became satisfied. I'll be waiting here to see you.... ;-)